# Provide "unlock codes" in a game to unlock all in-app purchase items

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to provide functionality in my game to enter a code in order to unlock all in-app purchase items in the game. The codes should be used only once. So I can give the code to someone to unlock all the items and the code then becomes invalid.

I wonder whether this can be accomplished by using the Unity In-App Purchase functionality only? We do not plan to run a backend service for the game. Also, the app does not require the user to login.

I am using Unity 2018.3.x and we plan to ship our app to Apple App Store and Google Play Store.

Thank you very much,
André

Comment: Ok guys, if you downvote this questions, please give a reason, so I can rephase it. Thx. But just downvoting does not really help...

Comment: How do you track who bought what?  There has to be a database somewhere.  As to the downvotes (wasn't me but...) I'd assume it's because this question is rather vague and open-ended.

Comment: @Immersive Thanks for your response. Yes, I know that the game needs to persist state somewhere in order to know which codes have been unlocked so far and which haven't. My hope simply was that Unity IAP together with app stores is able to handle this. If not, that's ok too. For the question: I know it's more of a generic conceptual questions. If there are better places to ask such questions I am happy to know about. Anyway, thank you for your comment on this. Highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I found was this post, about using promo codes directly from IAP toa void running a backend.

https://forum.unity.com/threads/solved-promo-codes-for-in-app.425690/

Comment: Interesting link! If I understand correctly, users of the app would have to redeem these promo codes in the app store somewhere. Will dig into this more. Anyway, thanks for the link!